# Substraction SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I want to substract two values of one column on a table :

Name of the table : statistic

> ```
> -|article|year|amount|
> -|-------|----|------|
> -|art1   |2018|289   |
> -|art2   |2018|4512  |
> -|art1   |2017|117   |
> -|art2   |2017|1230  |
> ...
> ```

I used this query but it didn't work :

> ```
> -SELECT
> -(CASE WHEN year = strftime('%Y', 'now') THEN s.amount END ) AS yearM,
> -(CASE WHEN year = strftime('%Y', 'now')-1 THEN s.amount END ) AS yearM1,
> -(yearM - yearM1) AS Delta
> -FROM statistic AS s
> ```

The columns yearM and yearM1 are contain values but the Delta column is Empty

I couldn't find where the problem is!

Comment: Are you sure that this query is executed without error? Which version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: yes no errors when executing this query. version 3

Comment: which version exactly? I tried in 3.12.2 and 3.21.0 and I am getting Error: no such column: yearM

Comment: yes i tried with another version and i got that error. In fact the yearM column from is the first line of the select query.

Comment: In which version of SQLite was this query executed without error? Also can you describe with more details what is your intention and what the expected result would be with the example data you have given?

Comment: i am working on SwingMobility application, SwingMobility is mobile CRM solution, i don't know exactly what version of sqlite is using exactly but i only know that it is version3. 
i expect the result to be like this: 
<blink>
-|yearM|yearM1|Delta|
-|289    |117      |172  |
-|4512  |1230    |3282|
</blink>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self-join:

```
select s1.amount as yearM, s2.amount as yearM1, (s1.amount-s2.amount) as Delta 
from statistic s1, statistic s2 
where s1.year=strftime('%Y', 'now') 
and s2.year=strftime('%Y', 'now')-1 
and s1.article=s2.article;
```